# import Axes3D issues

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pca

I'm using python 3.5 and i tried to import Axes3D from mpl_toolkitd.mplot3d but unfortunately i get this error:

```
In [1]: from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-357f877dbd2b> in <module>()
----> 1 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/__init__.py in <module>()
      2                         unicode_literals)
      3 
----> 4 from matplotlib.externals import six
      5 
      6 from .axes3d import Axes3D

ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.externals'
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be arising due to duplicate installation of matplotlib in your system.

Usually pip installs all external packages to:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib
```

On the other hand, apt-get installs your packages in :

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
```

Therefore, one way to resolve this would be try following (in order):

1. `sudo apt-get remove python3-matplotlib`
2. `sudo pip3 install matplotib`.